# Using VPN to be accessible from internet

Tags: vpn, ip, nat, port-forwarding

I am using a paid VPS for hosting game servers. My internet provider is providing me with dynamic IP's not accessible from internet (Nobody can see me - I am behind his internal NAT)

Is it possible to connect my PC to the VPN on the VPS and "get assigned" it's public IP?

The IP of the VPS is **46.36.40.3**
The IP of my PC is **93.91.150.68**

What I want to do is to connect to the VPS, tell it to bridge everything to my PC so my PC looks like it uses the IP 93.91.150.68 so I am able to be accessible from the internet.

I am not worrying about security or encryption, as the connection will be used only temporarily for testing various software

Answer (score 0):

I am sorry I cannot provide more detailed information.

Firstly, set up to use OpenVPN for example to connect to your server. There must be many tutorials.

Routing using that will be like using a NAT router.
Afterwards, just the way you would set up a port forwarding on your NAT router, you must set it up [Port forwarding for OpenVPN](https://serverfault.com/questions/834566/port-forwarding-with-openvpn)

The only thing you might adjust will be to use a fixed ip for your OpenVPN tunnel.

Comment: To be honest, I've already tried to set up OpenVPN on the VPS, I was able to connect to it, but I had no access to public internet and even VPN clients didn't see each other